# Python Keyboard module's functions will not work on macOS

Tags: python, module, automation, macros, keyboard

I have installed the python Keyboard module using
`pip install keyboard`
and the import works just fine.
This is my code:

```
import keyboard as kyb

kyb.add_abbreviation("@email", "test@example.com")
```

and it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
```

I tried researching but that did not help solve it. It also throws this error with other keyboard functions like "keyboard.add_hotkey()".